# SODA API: make query string 'starts with', 'ends with', 'containts', etc?

Tags: api, socrata

I need to do a search on a partial string.  ex: query string 'starts with', 'ends with', 'contains', etc

SODA API documentation doesn't cover much at all.

Tnx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the indexes we maintain on textual fields are pretty limited right now, so we don't yet support full text searches on individual fields like `contains`. However, we're working on a new platform that will allow us to provide a lot more query functionality like you're looking for. The options available on those columns are available in [our API docs for that datatype](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/datatypes/string.html).

Another option might be to use the [`$q` search parameter](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/queries.html#search-with-q), which *does* use a full-text index that spans all of the columns in the dataset. That may get you close to what you're looking for.

Can I help you with a query on a particular dataset you're working with?

Comment: $q worked. Tnx. (I did try it, but must have missed something earlier). Gonna tweet you if it's ok. Don't want to spam the thread.